# Distance between distributions and distance of moments

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let's say I have a sequence of random variables $X_n$ such that $$\mathbf E X_n^k = \mathbf E X^k+O(a_k/\sqrt{n})\quad\text{for all }k\in\mathbb N,\tag{$\ast$}$$ where $X$ is a random variable of standard (zero mean, unit variance) Gaussian distribution and $a_k$ are some constants which typically grow with $k$ (for my purposes they would be $a_k=(k/2)!$, for example).

Since the normal distribution is uniquely determined by its moments $(\ast)$ implies that $X_n\Rightarrow X$ weakly, as $n\to\infty$.

Is there an appropriate way to formalize the distance $d$ between the distributions of $X_n$ and $X$, such that $(\ast)$ implies $$d(X_n,X)=O(f(n))$$ for some function $f$? I think $(\ast)$ is not strong enough to control distance measures like the Kullback-Leibler divergence or the Hellinger distance, but there might be some appropriate weaker notion?

I think that $(\ast)$ implies $$\mathbf E f(X_n)=\mathbf E f(X)+O(1/\sqrt{n})$$ for a small class of test functions $f$, but depending on the growth of $a_k$, this class might be vary small.

Comment: How about the sup of modulus of the difference of characteristic functions over some complex disc around the origin? It's not a metric on the whole space of probability measures but on a space that seems big enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The natural thing to compare in this context seems to be the [moment generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) of $X_n$ and $X$.  In particular, consider:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E} \exp(t X_n) - \mathbf{E} \exp(t X) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!} \left( \mathbf{E} X_n^k - \mathbf{E} X^k \right) \\
&\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!} (k/2)! = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left( 1 + e^{t^2/4} \sqrt{\pi} t + e^{t^2/4} \sqrt{\pi} t \operatorname{Erf}(t/2) \right)
\end{align*} 
where we used the hypothesis given by the OP.

Given this bound on their moment generating functions (or a similar bound on the characteristic function), to what extent do the laws of $X_n$ and $X$ agree?   There seems to be an interesting discussion about this in the statistics literature.

- McCullagh, Peter. "Does the moment-generating function characterize a
  distribution?" The American Statistician 48.3 (1994): 208-208.
- Waller, Lance A. "Does the characteristic function numerically
  distinguish distributions?" The American Statistician 49.2 (1995):
  150-152.
- Luceño, Alberto. "Further evidence supporting the numerical
  usefulness of characteristic functions." The American Statistician
  51.3 (1997): 233-234.

Comment: I was not aware about this discussion in the statistics literature. Especially the McCullagh paper is somewhat surprising. Thanks for the interesting references!

Comment: A further comment: the above bound implies that the Lévy distance between $X_n$ and $X$ can be bounded by $c\frac{\log\log n}{\sqrt{\log n}}$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: @Julian A characterization of the Lévy distance I am familiar with is the one given in Problem 26.15 of the 4th edition of *Probability and Measure* by P. Billingsley.  However, I don't see how to combine the above bound and this characterization to obtain this result.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: This follows from the inequality $d_L(X_n,X)\leq \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^T \lvert \frac{\phi_n(t)-\phi(t)}{t}\rvert dt + \frac{2e\log T}{T}$ which holds for $T\geq 2$ and where $\phi_n, \phi$ are the characteristic functions of $X_n,X$. The above form is from Theorem 1.4.13., N. G. Ushakov. *Selected topics in characteristic functions*. Walter de Gruyter, 2011

Answer (score 5):

The classical approach to this is called "smoothing" and is described in Chapter 16 of Feller's *Introduction to Probability Theory*, Vol 2. Basically you use the bounds on the moment differences to bound the difference between the characteristic functions near the origin, then adjust a parameter (called $T$ by Feller) to get the best result.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a more general survey [Proximity of probability distributions in terms of Fourier–Stieltjes transforms](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/RM9749) by S.G.Bobkov. Using various integral estimates, just like some mentioned in the comments, he derives several bounds for Kolmogorov distance, total variation distance, KL-divergence and so on.

Bounding distances to standard normal using characteristic functions falls into Berry-Essen inequalities. Theorem 2.1 in Bobkov's work, for the Kolmogorov–Smirnov distance $d_{KS}$ gives:
$$
d_{KS}(X_n,X) \leqslant O(1)\cdot \int_{-T}^{T}\left|\frac{\Phi_n(t)-\Phi(t)}{t}\right|\mbox{d} t + O(T^{-1}).
$$
Under our assumptions (the series in the accepted answer shouldn't have a constant term!)
$$
|\Phi_n(t)-\Phi(t)| \leqslant O(n^{-1/2})\cdot t \mathrm{e}^{O(t^2)},
$$
so we obtain
$$
d_{KS}(X_n,X) \leqslant O(n^{-1/2})\cdot \mathrm{e}^{O(T^2)} + O(T^{-1}),
$$
and by optimizing over $T$ finally
$$
d_{KS}(X_n,X) \leqslant O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}\right).
$$