# Bounds on the distance between probability distributions in terms characteristic functions

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I am looking for the bounds on the distance between probability distributions in terms characteristic functions.

For example, I am aware of the following bound
\begin{align}
d(P,Q) \le \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T}^T \frac{|\phi_P(t)-\phi_Q(t)|}{t} dt+ \frac{q_{max}}{ \pi T}
\end{align}
where  the $d(P,Q)$ is the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance and $q_{max}$ the maximum value of the pdf of $Q$.

Specifically, am looking for the bonds that would depend on the following difference

\begin{align}
| t \phi_P^{\prime}(t)+\phi_P(t)-(t \phi_Q^{\prime}(t)+\phi_Q(t)) |
\end{align}

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I think you put a reference to my question.

Comment: related (corrected link): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254237/distance-between-distributions-and-distance-of-moments